# Calculate a squared complex number

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, discrete-mathematics, complex-numbers

I have the following number that I have to calculate the square but I have doubts on the complex part... Can someone help me solving my problem?

$$\left(\frac{2-4(\cos(2 \pi \nu ) - j \sin(2 \pi \nu))}{2-(\cos(2 \pi \nu ) - j \sin(2 \pi \nu))}\right)^2$$

Thank you

Comment: With what are you exactly struggling?

Comment: $\cos(2 \pi \nu ) - j \sin(2 \pi \nu))=\exp(-2\pi\nu i)$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I'm started from your form but I need the square of the form in the request

Comment: there is missing brackets in the denominator which may cause ambiguity

Comment: @BigBoy : The fact that you need the bottom line in a form that separates the real and imaginary parts doesn't mean you can't use J.W.Tanner's suggestion along the way.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner : Wouldn't it be better to write that equality in the form $\cos(2\pi\nu)-j\sin(2\pi\nu) = \exp(-2\pi\nu j) \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: Yes, @MichaelHardy, I should have typed $j$ where I typed $i$

Comment: when I square the number the $j$ remains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you square the numerator and denominator separately and then do the division, you get the same result as if you divide first and then square, so which is better may be just a matter of which costs you the least effort. I'm not sure which one that will be.
\begin{align}
& \frac{2 - 4\exp(-2\pi\nu j)}{2 - \exp(-2\pi\nu j)} \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{2 - 4\exp(-2\pi\nu j)}{2 - \exp(-2\pi\nu j)} \cdot \frac{2-\exp(2\pi\nu j)}{2-\exp(2\pi\nu j)} \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{4 - 2\exp(2\pi\nu j)-8\exp(-2\pi\nu j) + 4}{2 - 2\exp(2\pi\nu j) - 2\exp(-2\pi\nu j) + 1} \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{8 - 2(\cos(2\pi\nu ) + j\sin(2\pi \nu)) -8(\cos(2\pi\nu) - j\sin(2\pi\nu))}{3- 4\cos(2\pi\nu)} \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{8 - 10\cos(2\pi\nu)}{3-4\cos(2\pi\nu)} + j \frac{6\sin(2\pi\nu)}{3-4\cos(2\pi\nu)} \\[10pt]
= {} & a+bj
\end{align}
Next use the identity $(a+bj)^2 = (a^2-b^2) + 2abj.$

Possibly some simplifications based on trigonometric identities may follow.

Comment: A question... some of my collegue when pass from exponential form to polar form and made the $(...)^2$, remove the $j$, an example: $\frac{2(1-e^{-j2 \pi \nu })}{2-e^{-j2 \pi \nu}}$ and when we start with the next step I have $(\frac{2(1-2cos(2 \pi \nu )+2sin(2 \pi \nu))}{2-cos(2 \pi \nu)+ sin(2 \pi \nu)})^{2}$ have you any idea?

Comment: @BigBoy : I haven't yet succeeded in understanding your comment above.

Comment: I haven't understand why in many exercises (signal exercises) the $j$ disappear and I thought that it's a math problema but maybe no

Comment: @BigBoy : Possibly some form of the identity $\dfrac{\exp(jz) + \exp(-jx)} 2 = \cos x$ was used, but I'd have to know the specifics.

Comment: I have solved (maybe) the problem... the module of a complex number remove the $j$